# Revealing / Hiding Fixed Menu (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix and animate a header navigation so that it pops down from outside of the browser window when a user scrolls past 80px from the top. I then want to reverse the animation when the user scrolls back past <80px. I have gotten this far (have set throttle function earlier in the code):

```
var e = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).on("scroll", throttle(function() {
        var t = $(window).scrollTop();
        t > 80 ? t > e ? $(header).animate({
          top: "-150px"
        }, 200) :
```

At the 'else' point I am totally stuck. I've been looking at other similar functions and trying to interpret the code but really struggling. Any help hugely appreciated.

Comment: Why are you comparing it with `e` (which will be usually `0`). That's no point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you comparing it with `e` (which will be usually `0`). That's no point. If you want something to happen when the `window`'s `scrollTop` becomes `80px`, just use the following code. Also please not the single `true` parameter in the `animate`'s `stop()` function.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".peek-a-boo").css({
    top: -200
  });
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80)
      $(".peek-a-boo").stop(true).animate({
        top: 0
      }, 200);
    else
      $(".peek-a-boo").animate({
        top: -200
      }, 200);
  });
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.peek-a-boo {position: fixed; background-color: #99f; width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;}
.heighter {height: 1000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="peek-a-boo">Peek</header>
<div class="heighter"></div>
```